# Recording xy coordinates of a mouse click on an image in Google Sheets using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, excel, image-processing, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I obtain the XY coordinates of an image when I click on [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTcT0.png) in Google Sheets via App Scripts? I have tried the following but I am new to App Script and the Google API isn't helping.

```
function test(e) {
  
  Browser.msgBox('You clicked it!');
  
  
  var yCoordinate = e.clientY;
  var xCoordinate = e.clientX;
```

There were related questions on this topic using javascript which is slightly different from Google's Apps Script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the image is in the spreadsheet itself, not a custom HTML view, then this is not something you can do.

Comment: You might try using onSelectionChange().  Use Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) to see the event object but e.range.columStart and e.range.rowStart could be what you're looking for perhaps

Comment: @Diego the image I have is in the spreadsheet. What is a custom HTML view? I am open to other workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is a script that you [assigned to an image embedded in the spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets).

If that's the case, then its not possible to retrieve the co-ordinates of the image. The function attached to the image does not receive an event object as a parameter.

However, there is a feature request for this very thing on Google's Issue Tracker. See link below:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122937060

Be sure to star the request to increase it's visibility.

Comment: yes it is what I want exactly. How come [this](https://temboo.com/processing/save-to-spreadsheet) is possible?